# Dart/Flutter - Cannot get encoding by name

Tags: flutter, dart, encoding, ascii, codepages

I need to use [Code Page 850](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp850.html) Ascii encoding for an issue I have, but not sure how to access/use it in Dart.

Ultimately, I need to convert a hexadecimal string to ascii. The hexadecimal includes special characters that aren't in generic ascii. Which is why I need cp850.

I've tried to access this encoding by calling the `Encoding.getByName()` function

```
// returns null
Encoding? encoding = Encoding.getByName('ibm850');
```

`ibm850` appears to be the right name for cp850, based on the [character sets accepted](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml) for this function.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the following package which seems to have support for cp850: https://pub.dev/packages/charset ? It does at least have this global variable defined: https://pub.dev/documentation/charset/latest/charset/cp850.html

Comment: @julemand101 this package worked like a charm, great find! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package [`charset`](https://pub.dev/packages/charset) to encode/decode from/to various different character sets. E.g. you can do the following to decode some bytes encoded in cp850 by doing the following:

```dart
import 'package:charset/charset.dart' as charset;

void main() {
  final cp850EncodedMessage = [
    82, 155, 100, 32, 103, 114, 155, 100, 32, 109, 101, //
    100, 32, 102, 108, 155, 100, 101, 32, 112, 134, 33, //
  ];

  print(charset.cp850.decode(cp850EncodedMessage));
  // Rød grød med fløde på!
}
```